# Why can't I execute this script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to execute a string (actually it's a part of a longer string that I split into different strings.

my error message is tr1.sh: 3: tr1.sh: Bad substitution

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d ${HOME }/ trashbin  ]
then  mkdir ${HOME }/ trashbin
fi
```

Comment: are you sure you're invoking it using bash?

Comment: maybe remove some of those spaces in there. or does your "trashbin" directory REALLY start with a space char? Right now you're trying the equivalent of `mkdir ${HOME }; mkdir trashbin`

Comment: I removed the space characters but it does not change anything

Comment: Yes I invoked #!/bin/bash

Comment: If you haven't made the script executable, it will not execute. Test with `bash scriptname`. If that works, then `chmod 0755 scriptname` and try `./scriptname` (sorry added -c by mistake :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the spaces:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d ${HOME}/trashbin  ]
then  mkdir ${HOME}/trashbin
fi
```

Comment: +1. The particular reason why it's failing is that `HOME<space>` is not a valid variable name (unlike `HOME`).

Comment: Sure, I'm new here, didn't figured it out yet :)